# React-Query staleTime set to 0 increase the time to load our Home page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

In our iOS `react-native@0.66.3` application that use `react-query@3.34.16`,

We are experiencing latency to load our home page after we reduced the `staleTime` to `0` globally for `react-query`

This is the commit that added the latency :

https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/commit/1c8ea9b0bb4ff40206d606ea150e1853d01b4d0c

**before**

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/77674046/156797772-d0f81bf3-fcfe-4d1f-945e-a4a4f377747f.MP4

**after**

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/77674046/156797911-be409b24-ef64-4a75-b9e6-b853b64c3d1f.MP4

Using our older version on Test flight, we can see that before this commit, the home page takes `3secs` to load, now it takes `10secs`.

We cannot revert the commit because it's required for our offline mode

We don't get why it is not that slow on Android, can anyone help us understand what is going on?